# Combine NEXT function with a variable (named range) from the name manager

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA to insert a value into each sheet using the `NEXT` function:

```
Sub Insert_Values()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
    Dim Range As Range
    Set Range = b.Range("B2:C4")
    b.Select
    Range.Value = 1
Next b
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now I want to use a `named range` instead of `Set Range = b.Range("B2:C4")`. 
Therefore, I assigned `Range_01` in the `name manager` to the `Range("B2:C4")` looking like this:

---

[image]

---

In the VBA I changed:

```
Dim Range As Range
Set Range = b.Range("Range_01")
```

Now, I get `runtime error 1004`.

I assume the reason is that in the `name manager` the `Sheet1` is fixed assigned to the `Range_01`. 
Therefore, I am wondering if there is way to assign a `named range` but without a fixed `Sheet` so the `NEXT` function can still run through all sheets?

Comment: Side note: don't use `Range` as a variable name... use something different.

Comment: A named range does not belong to a sheet object. It belongs to the Workbook object. You can just use `Range("Range_01")` for all sheets... `Debug.Print  Range("Range_01").Rows.Count` will return correctly. You can also test it like `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Names("Fructe").RefersTo`. And follow BigBen's advice!

Comment: @FaneDuru - you can just use `Range("Range_01")` for all sheets - no this is not correct - as the accepted answer shows.

Comment: @BigBen: Maybe not the most elegant way, but if it works, why it is  not correct? Of course, if the named range value is always the same. Otherwise, I do not see any reason to use the naming facility.

Comment: @FaneDuru - my point is that it doesn't work. Also to expand on your previous comment - named ranges can either have worksheet or workbook scope. So your first two sentences are not correct either.

Comment: @BigBen: I'm afraid, this is not true... Please, name some range in a worksheet and use it like I suggested, activating any other worksheet. Its value will always be the same. Independent of the sheet...

Comment: @FaneDuru - this is not the place for discussion like this, but named ranges can have *either* global or local scope. OP is looking to use a range on *each* sheet, not a named range on one specific sheet. Which is why the posted and accepted answer using the named range's *address* to refer to the corresponding range *on each sheet*. Which is why your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @Michi: Would you like to use the values kept in the named range, or only use the named range address, but needing values of each sheet for that specific address?

Comment: You could use `b.Range(Range("Range_01").Address)`.

Comment: @SJR: You use that only in case that you are not interested in the **named range values** and only want to exploit the name address and, in fact you want using the values **in the `b` sheet for that specific range address**, I'm afraid... Am I wrong?

Comment: @FaneDuru - yes, and there's no indication from OP that he is interested in the values.

Comment: @SJR: It isn't, indeed. I just presumed that naming a range, most probably you need to use that specific range values... But, I may be wrong, of course. In fact, he appreciated the answer like being 'exactly what he needed'. But, maybe he was just satisfied that the bloody error does not appear any more... ;)

Comment: @FaneDuru - well you can use the address or any other property of a named range, just as with any other range. I'm not entirely clear what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @SJR: Agreed! That's why I asked him about this issue clarification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your final objective is, but you could use the `Address` property.

```
Sub Insert_Values()

Dim b As Worksheet, s As String

s = Range("Range_01").Parent.Range("Range_01").Address 'B2:C4
'or just s = Range("Range_01").Address

For Each b In Worksheets
    Dim Range1 As Range 'use a better name!
    Set Range1 = b.Range(s)
    Range1.Value = 1
Next b

End Sub
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Michi: Would you like to use the values kept in the named range, or only use the named range address, but needing values of each sheet for that specific address?